# UISlider Thumbnail position offset

Tags: ios, uislider

I'm trying to implement a standard UISlider with a custom image.

Currently it looks like so

[image]

But I need it to look like this

[image]

How do I offset the thumbnail up so only the tip barely touches the line?

Comment: have you found any solution for it?

Comment: @mohsin nope :( I finally ended up abandoning the whole slider idea and moved on implementing it otherwise. But it would still be useful to know how to do it in the future..

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the offset of the thumb image you have to override `thumbRectForBounds:trackRect:value:` in a custom `UISlider` subclass.

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {
    override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
        let originalRect = super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
        let yOffset: CGFloat = 16 // any value you want
        let newY = originalRect.origin.y - yOffset

        return CGRect(x: originalRect.origin.x, y: newY, width: originalRect.width, height: originalRect.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the value of slideBar changed, you can get the thumb position by following codes.

```
    let slideBounds = self.slideBar.bounds
    let trackRt = self.slideBar.trackRect(forBounds: slideBounds)

    // thumbRt is in slideBar coordination.
    let thumbRt = self.slideBar.thumbRect(forBounds: slideBounds, trackRect: trackRt, value: slideBar.value)

    // Get center point of slideBar with coordination of `self`.
    let centerPt = self.convert(CGPoint(x: thumbRt.midX, y: thumbRt.midY), from: self.slideBar)

    // Let a UILabel moving with thumb image of slideBar.
    var origPt = self.lblValue.center
    origPt.x = centerPt.x
    self.lblValue.center = origPt
```